Backward mysql table search
I have a mysql database that contains data collected from various weather sensors and the like.
All the data is easy to handle apart from the raw rain fall which is by nature incremental but can be reset to zero from time to time ether from the internal 12bit counter wrapping or a simple power failure. example of data (much simplified):
|   time     |           rain_raw   |
| 1716805915 |       37.55905511796 |
| 1716806011 |       37.55905511796 |
| 1716806107 |       37.55905511796 |
| 1716806203 |       37.55905511796 |
| 1716806251 |       37.55905511796 |<------ Need to find this row
| 1716807098 |                    0 |
| 1716807146 |                    0 |
| 1716807866 |                    0 |
| 1716822169 |                    0 |
| 1716822217 |       0.011811023622 |
| 1716822265 |       0.011811023622 |
| 1716822361 |       0.011811023622 |
| 1716822409 |       0.011811023622 |
| 1716822457 |       0.011811023622 |
| 1716822505 |       0.011811023622 |
| 1716822553 |       0.023622047244 |
| 1716822601 |       0.023622047244 |
| 1716822649 |       0.023622047244 |
| 1716822697 |       0.023622047244 |<------ Current last entry

The first column is the time (seconds from epoch) the second the amount of rain in inches. I dont want to search top down for two reasons the database is large so I feel this is inefficient and secondly there are a number of data gliches (historical data not important currently) which can trigger false positives with the forward search I have tried. I need to find the indicated row so that I can use the rain fall value as an adder to subsequent entries.
So my question, is there and efficient way to search backwards from the current last entry to the point where the data got reset. I am using Mariadb with Qt6 and C++.
Thanks for any help.
This is my current foward search:
SELECT time,rain_raw 
FROM weather_data t1 
WHERE rain_raw > (
    SELECT rain_raw 
    FROM weather_data t2 
    WHERE t1.rain_raw > t2.rain_raw 
    ORDER BY time desc 
    LIMIT 1 
);

This worked with a simple data set but was not good with the actual data set I wish to use.

Are you using a version of MariaDB with window functions?

is it always 0 after a reset?  or just less than the earlier value?

explain "not good"; was it wrong for some data?  too slow? something else?

how many rows are there?

I have very little knowledge of SQL my MariaDB was built from the Beyond Linux From Scrach project I don't know if it supports window functions.

After a reset the safe answer would be just less (by a large amount) than the earlier value.

My test dataset has 96000 entries the running dataset currently 289616 entries.

Both have a few rows that have corrupted values in them this happens if the radio receiver mangles the data, this has improved with later versions of the radio receiver system firmware and my parsing software has implemented more checking. I need the historical data for a separate piece of work looking at weather trends over time.

Apart from not handling the few corrupted entries my current solution takes several seconds to complete on the test dataset. I could (and probably will) remove the few bad values but there is a probability that new ones could happen at a later time so I am looking for a solution that will eventually self heal but first things first.

This is just out of my head, I have not created any test tables:
SELECT time,rain_raw
FROM weather_data t1
WHERE t1.time < (
  SELECT time FROM weather_data t2
  WHERE t2.rain_raw = 0 ORDER BY time desc LIMIT 1
)
AND t2.rain_raw > 0
ORDER BY t1.time DESC
LIMIT 1;


ScifiBob has already given an answer for finding the row mentioned in your question.
This is a suggestion for an alternative approach. Instead of

find the indicated row so that I can use the rain fall value as an adder to subsequent entries.

You could use the LAG() window function to add the per row rainfall diffs, and then sum them up to get the cumulative totals, ignoring any diffs that are negative:
WITH rainfall_with_prev (time, rain_raw, rain_raw_prev) AS (
    SELECT time, rain_raw, LAG(rain_raw) OVER (ORDER BY time ASC)
    FROM weather_data
)
SELECT time,
  SUM(
    IF(
      rain_raw_prev IS NULL,
      rain_raw,
      GREATEST(rain_raw - rain_raw_prev, 0))
  ) OVER (ORDER BY time ASC) AS cumulative_rain
FROM rainfall_with_prev;

Here's a db<>fiddle.

On reflection this solution looks like a better approach, it is late here now so I will have a look in the morning. I will update my test dataset with a copy of the current running dataset (warts and all) and do a full evaluation.

Plan A Which of the other answers works best for you?  If none are "fast enough", then we can discuss three other approaches and some tips:
Plan B Build and maintain a Summary Table to avoid rereading old data again and again
Plan C  Self-JOIN to align one row with prev/next.  (If LAG() is well-optimized, this Plan is not worth the effort.)
Plan D A design change to eliminate the question and save even more space:

Remove that rainfall column from that table.  (Saves lots of space and speeds up various things.)
Have a separate table with just the time and rainfall since last read,  (Much smaller table [assuming you are not in a rainforest].)
Leave out rows that don't change.  (Again saves space and speeds up things.)
Deal with "reset-to zero" while inserting (instead of while reading).  This takes extra code during the INSERT phase, but greatly simplifies the SELECT phase.
A 1-row table could keep the last-seen rain amount; this makes the above optimizations easy:
If the reading goes down, then it was a "reset"; just update 1-row table.
If the reading stays the same, do nothing.
if the reading goes up, take the diff and store into new table and update 1-row table.

A space-saving tip  In all cases...  It looks like rainfall is currently stored in an 8-byte DOUBLE.  To save a significant amount of space, use a 4-byte FLOAT would have adequate precision (about 7 significant digits).  Or maybe a 3-byte DECIMAL(6,2) (max of 9999.99, 2 decimal places.
Note: Comparing diff datatypes (FLOAT/DOUBLE/DECIMAL) can say "not equal" when they are logically "equal".  So Be consistent.  (Testing for 0 always works "correctly".)
More discussion:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_sensor
